# LangDetectException: how to fix it, by adding all rows not detected as 'Other'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to detect the language in a pandas data frame.

```
 df['Lang'] = df['Text'].apply(detect)
```

but I am getting this error:

```
LangDetectException: No features in text.
```

My dataset is

```
Text

Describe what you've tried
Je m'appelle Mondly
Je suis désolé
¿Cómo estás?
Добрый день
Includi errori
...
5
```

Expected output:

```
Text                               Lang

Describe what you've tried         English
Je m'appelle Mondly                French 
Je suis désolé                     French 
¿Cómo estás?                       Spanish
Добрый день                        Russian 
Includi errori                     Italian
...                                ...
do widzenia                        Polish
5                                  Other
```

I think the problem with this error is in the length of some rows. To avoid this error, I should add probably.a condition which sets the length of a sentence to a minimum of two words. Otherwise, I could just include all the rows whose language was not detected as 'Other'.

The problem seems be caused by the following:

```
['. ', '❤️❤️❤️', '5/10',nan, '  ']
```

so it can make sense to group them in a new category.

Can you please tell me where the error is and how to fix it in order to get the expected output?

Thanks

Comment: You're code works fine for me in Python 3.7.6 with Pandas 1.0.1. Can you give a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function for the `apply` function that returns 'Other' whenever `langdetect.detect` cannot process the content.

```py
def det(x):
    try:
        lang = detect(x)
    except:
        lang = 'Other'
    return lang

df['Lang'] = df['Text'].apply(det)
```